# Stuck on Leetcode 19 Question "Remove Nth Node From End of List"

Tags: javascript, linked-list, runtime-error

I have an error occurring on let `forwardNode = currentNode.next.next` the error is "TypeError: Cannot read property on 'next' of null. But when I console.log currentNode.next its not null.

I then broke down `let forwardNode = currentNode.next.next` to:

```
let forwardNode = currentNode.next 
let forward = forwardNode.next 
currentNode = forward
```

But I get the same error. I'm stuck! I don't know what I'm overlooking here. Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {ListNode}
 */


var removeNthFromEnd = function(head, n) {
    let currentNode = head
    let currentIndex = 0 

    while (currentNode.next != null  ) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next 
        currentIndex++
    }

    //length of LL is known by currentIndex
    //reset currentnode 


    currentNode = head

    for (let i = 0; i<currentIndex-n; i++){
        currentNode = currentNode.next
    }

    let forwardNode = currentNode.next.next 
    currentNode.next = forwardNode 


    return head
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At that point in the code, there are just `n` nodes behind `currentNode`. If `n` is `0`, `currentNode.next` does not exist, thus `.next.next` doesn't work at all. You only want to execute the whole code if `n` isn't 0.

Comment: I added another pointer who's next value is set to null if ```n``` equals 0 but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: This is the edited version but still same error. https://repl.it/repls/PromotedRecentFilesize

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work if the node to be removed is 2 from last or first node from last. You need to handle those use cases explicitly. Because current.next may be null in one case and current.next.next will also be null in other case.